# Image Classification using Random Forests in OpenCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, random-forest

can canyone guide me on how I train a random forests classifier on Camera input video in OpenCV? 
What I wish to do is:

1. Get frame from VideoCapture object
2. Locate object in frame
3. Draw a bounding box around the object and sample it
4. Store the sample in a buffer and train a random forests classifier on-line
5. Update the object model
6. Track the object in next frame using updated object model
7. Go back to step 2

This approach is inspired from the TLD predator algorithm and I took a loot at openTLD as well however, I dont understand the implementation of openTLD too well and would like to create it myself.

I have completed till step 3 using a haar-based cascading classifier but im a bit lost about image classification on random forests and updating the model.

Any help and guidance on this is greatly appreciated!
Sincere thanks!